# Low random read IOPs for 5 SSDs in hardware RAID5 setup

Tags: linux, ssd, hardware-raid

We have 5 Toshiba Px04Srb192 SSDs (270K random read IOP as per spec), setup in hardware Raid5. Running fio is giving 250K IOPs which is much below what I was expecting.

```
/fio --randrepeat=1 --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --gtod_reduce=1 --name=test --filename=/ae/disk1/test --bs=4k --iodepth=96 --numjobs=1 --size=8g --readwrite=randread

test: (g=0): rw=randread, bs=4K-4K/4K-4K, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=96
fio-2.0.9
Starting 1 process
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [r] [100.0% done] [961.6M/0K /s] [246K/0  iops] [eta 00m:00s]
test: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=342604: Tue Feb 12 23:58:01 2019
  read : io=8192.0MB, bw=991796KB/s, iops=247948 , runt=  8458msec
  cpu          : usr=10.88%, sys=87.74%, ctx=437, majf=0, minf=115
  IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.1%, 4=0.1%, 8=0.1%, 16=0.1%, 32=0.1%, >=64=100.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.1%
     issued    : total=r=2097152/w=0/d=0, short=r=0/w=0/d=0

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
   READ: io=8192.0MB, aggrb=991795KB/s, minb=991795KB/s, maxb=991795KB/s, mint=8458msec, maxt=8458msec

Disk stats (read/write):
  sdb: ios=2083688/0, merge=0/0, ticks=265238/0, in_queue=265020, util=98.53

lspci -nn | grep RAID
18:00.0 RAID bus controller [0104]: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID Tri-Mode SAS3508 [1000:0016] (rev 01)
```

I was expecting 5 SSDs IOPs to be at least 2 times individual SSD. Is that right? Any suggestions why we are seeing low IOPs?

Comment: I suspect the RAID controller is the bottleneck. Can you get its perf stats? Otherwise, start with a single drive and see if you can even get 270K iops

Answer (score 1):

First, you expect 270k iops as per spec, but what is the block size required to meet this value ? is it actually 4k io size in the spec ?

Second, if you use a single io thread to benchmark your raid5, you will never be able to show the overall read performance of your raid5. Each read io is served by only 1 SSD drive. So you have to increase the workers count (fio numjobs parameter) to at least 5.

Comment: While I agree that increasing `numjobs` may help reach higher "hero" numbers I'm not sure the statement "Each read io is served by only 1 SSD drive" covers the entire situation. The question author is using `libaio` with `direct=1` with `iodepth=96`. That means there can be up to 96 outstanding I/Os at any given time split across all the disks (i.e. we have asynchronous submission from a single thread/process). If each SSD only had an internal queue depth of only 19 or the RAID controller's maximum depth is only 96 then what was done would be already at the limits...

Comment: yes, 270 K random reads for 4k. I tried increasing numjobs but IOPS don't go beyond ~250K

Answer (score 1):

(Your version of fio is ancient! See https://github.com/axboe/fio/releases to see what upstream has reached...)

The feedback you're getting in other answers is good but I'd like to highlight this:

```
  cpu          : usr=10.88%, sys=87.74%, ctx=437, majf=0, minf=115
```

If we sum your userspace and kernel system percentages together we get 98.62%. There is a strong suggestion that you have no more CPU time left to send more I/Os (note you're already using the go-faster stripe of `gtod_reduce=1` which I normally recommend against but it looks appropriate in your case).

There are a few other things though...

```
  sdb: ios=2083688/0, merge=0/0, ticks=265238/0, in_queue=265020, util=98.53
```

This is hinting that the "disk" your RAID controller is presenting is very busy (look at that `util` percentage). That is something to bear in mind.

Are you doing I/O through a file within a filesystem (`/ae/disk1/`)? If so, are you aware that the filesystem will impose some overhead and may not offer the `O_DIRECT` behaviour you're expecting? You probably want to start by doing I/O at the block level (i.e. `/dev/sdb`) and work your way up to be able to attribute what any overhead is (WARNING: be careful - fio can destroy data when misused).

If you're really going to go faster I think you will need to:

- Do I/O at the block device level.
- Use multiple threads or processes (e.g. by increasing `numjobs`). That way the fio threads/processes are likely to migrate to different CPUs (but note everything comes with a cost)...
- Start tweaking fio to submit and reap I/O in batches.
- Start tweaking your kernel.

As I stated it is rare that most people need to go to these lengths but maybe you're one of the exceptions :-). An fio mailing list thread reply "[Re: Recommended Job File For Stress Testing PCI-E](https://www.spinics.net/lists/fio/msg05984.html)" mentions this:

> You might see a benefit (more load per disk) using threads (thread)
>   rather than processes. You may also need to use more than one thread
>   per disk. See http://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html for
>   more options. Both https://www.spinics.net/lists/fio/msg05451.html and
>   http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=140313968523237&w=2 give examples
>   of people using fio to drive high load so those might be more useful.

Comment: Thanks Anon for detailed explanation. Let me try your recommendations.